# Why does "a different-coloured ink" make sense? I can find meaningful only "different-coloured inks"

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/coloured_1):
**(1)** *The words are written in a different-coloured ink*.

To me, "*a different-coloured ink*" is nonsense because:
one colour corresponds to one ink;
different coloures can correspond only to different inks;
different coloures cannot correspond to one ink.

Why does "*a different-coloured ink*" make sense?

my variant:
**(2)** *The words are written in different-coloured inks*.
What is the difference between (1) and (2)?

Comment: ***The words*** refers to ***some specific words within some larger block of text***. The specific words of interest are printed using a different colour ink to the main surrounding text. Introducing plural ***inks*** looks silly - it suggests the specific words of interest might be written using some kind of "rainbow" font where each *letter* uses a different colour.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You wrote: "_Introducing plural inks looks silly - ... some kind of "rainbow" font_" Why is it silly? If you see a rainbow, you turn your head away with an angry face?

Comment: @Loviii - look up the definition of 'twisting my words'.

Comment: It's "silly" because *to this native speaker*, with plural ***inks*** the words don't make sense (or, as I suggested, they imply a bizarre scenario). You yourself said that using singular ***ink*** is "nonsense". The difference is I'm right and you're wrong, but I'm not getting angry about anything.

Comment: @DoneWithThis. I twisted the words only in the second question about a rainbow. The first question "_Why is it silly_" doesn't twist the words.

Comment: @Loviii - the twist was in comparing the rainbow to anger. You turned the phrase to your own meaning, & away from its intent.

Comment: "I saw a big dog yesterday. Today I saw a different dog." I guess the OP wouldn't consider that grammatical either. (Although I admit that usage examples in dictionaries often don't give enough context to see exactly how they're used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**different-colo(u)red inks** refers to inks of multiple colors.

> She drew a picture of a flower garden using different-coloured inks.

"different-colored ink"  could be paraphrased as "ink of a different color"

> We're using blue ink for "garage sale". Maybe we should choose a different-colored ink for the date. How about red?
>
> The only pen in the drawer is a ball-point pen with purple ink. I would prefer to write with different-colored ink. Purple makes me want to dot my i's with a heart.

Comment: According to dictionaries, we can use the adjective "_multicolo(u)r_" instead of "_multicolo(u)r**ed**_". By analogy with this, can we use the adjective "_different-colo(u)r_" instead of "_different-colo(u)r**ed**_"? Thanks.

Comment: **multicolor** means "having many colors" the same as "multicolored". *She was wearing a multicolor skirt.*  I have heard **different color**  used by children to mean "of a different color". For example, a child might be drawing with a pack of colored chalks and say something like *I need different color chalk for the puppy's nose*.

Answer (score 2):

This is referring to some specific words within a larger body of words, with those words being written in *a different-coloured ink* to the rest of the text.

For example, I could ask someone to add some instructions to a process and to write that "Step 7 must be completed exactly as described" and to ask then to write those words "in a different-coloured ink" for emphasis.

So overall, the instructions are written in "different-coloured inks", with step 7 being specifically in "a different-coloured ink".

Comment: In the first line of my reply, some words are written in 'a different style' (italic). If SO allowed colours in answers, I could have written them in 'a different-coloured "ink"'